# Triangle border with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I want to create a background of a heading like below using only CSS:

[image]

I am able to create the triangle, but unable to position it correctly. 
The HTML is simple as:

```
<h1><a href="#">Link ...</a></h1>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
h1{ 
    margin: 20px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 0 0 50px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0000ff;
}
```

JSFiddle Demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/yGsny/

Comment: @Sowmya sorry, added the image.

Comment: You didn't close your h1 tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution at your problem:

```
  h1{
        background:blue;
        line-height:30px;
        padding:0 20px;
        width:50px;
        position:relative;
    }
    a{color:white; text-decoration:none;}
    h1:before{
        position:absolute;
        left:100%;
        top:0;
        content:"";
        border:30px solid blue;
        border-width:0px 30px 30px 0px;
        border-color:transparent transparent blue transparent;
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMwdS/1/)

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps 
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/
The triangles below the bubbles.

Also there are many more useful articles on the site which may help.

Answer (score 0):

try using padding + negative text-indent, this should work for you :)